# How to filter posts modified after specific date in Wordpress API v2

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wp-api

I am trying to fetch(filter) the posts modified after specific date through WordPress REST API `2.0-beta15` & WordPress `v4.8.3` and update that with the existing posts in my client app.

Using `after` and `before` query params provided by WordPress I can filter posts based on `date` instead of `modified` field.

I have tried `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[date_query][0][column]=post_modified_gmt&filter[date_query][0][after]=1+month+ago` using this https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter as mentioned [in this issue](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2706), but this `date_query` filter is also not working now.

I need any option like

http://bankersdaily.in/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?modified_after=2017-10-31T13:32:10&_envelope
http://bankersdaily.in/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?after=2017-10-31T13:32:10&field=modified&_envelope

References:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query?#Date_Parameters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like it's not supported, skimming through the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts)

Here are some workarounds:

**1) Custom `modified_after` rest query parameter**

We can add the `modified_after` rest query parameter for the `post` post type with:

```
add_filter( 'rest_post_collection_params', function( $query_params ) {
    $query_params['modified_after'] = [
        'description' => __( 'Limit response to posts published after a given ISO8601 compliant date.' ),
        'type'        => 'string',
        'format'      => 'date-time',
    ];
    return $query_params;
} );
```

and then modify the rest post query accordingly with:

```
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', function( $args, $request ) {
    if( isset( $request['modified_after'] ) && ! isset( $request['after'] ) ) {
        $args['date_query'][0]['after'] = $request['modified_after'];
        $args['date_query'][0]['column'] = 'post_modified';
    }
    return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

where we let `after` take priority over `modified_after`.

**Example:**

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts??modified_after=2017-11-07T00:00:00
```

**Notes:**

We might have used `modified_gmt_after` for the `post_modified_gmt` column.

It might be better to use a more unique name than `modified_after` to avoid a possible future name collision.

To extend this to other post types, we can use the `rest_{$post_type}_collection_params` and the `rest_{$post_type}_query` filters.

Another option is to create a custom endpoint and parameters, that's a more work to do there. It's of course a question if we should add a custom parameter to the current rest api. In some cases it should be ok, as we're not removing or modifying the response, or changing how other parameters work.

**2) Custom `date_query_column` rest query parameter**

Another approach would be to introduce a custom `date_query_column` rest query parameter:

```
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', function( $args, $request ) {
    if ( ! isset( $request['before'] ) && ! isset( $request['after'] ) )
        return $args;

    if( isset( $request['date_query_column'] ) )
        $args['date_query'][0]['column'] = $request['date_query_column'];

    return $args;
}, 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'rest_post_collection_params', function( $query_params ) {
    $query_params['date_query_column'] = [
            'description' => __( 'The date query column.' ),
            'type'        => 'string',
            'enum'        => [ 'post_date', 'post_date_gmt', 'post_modified', 'post_modified_gmt', 'comment_date', 'comment_date_gmt' ],
        ];
    return $query_params;
} );
```

that would be available if either `after` or `before` parameters are set.

**Example:**

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts??after=2017-11-07T00:00:00&date_query_column=post_modified
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can I add the above `add_filter` code here https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter/blob/master/plugin.php#L18 after fork & using that updated plugin will work?

Comment: @VigneshSundar I wouldn't recommend to modify the core code, instead [create a custom plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin). That way you don't loose the modifications each time you update WordPress core.

Comment: But I think [rest-filter](https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter) is not part of [WP-API merged with WordPress core](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API), it is a plugin we can add separately & updating WordPress will not affect this

Comment: My approach was without that plugin in mind. I would also avoid modify 3rd party plugins for the same reason. Im on mobile now so I will check it later

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I will create new plugin, But FYI few words from rest-filter description just now I was seen - '[removed from the API when it was merged into WordPress core](https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter/blob/master/plugin.php#L4)'

Answer (score 11):

### Native Support - WordPress 5.7

As of WordPress 5.7, support has been added for querying by the post modified date rather than the published date. Custom workarounds are no longer required.

Usage:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?modified_after=2021-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

Notes: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/02/23/rest-api-changes-in-wordpress-5-7/

Comment: apparently it is not documented yet: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/

Comment: Can confirm that this is now in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I have created a WordPress plugin [WP REST API – Filter posts date wise using given column](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-filter-posts-date-wise-using-given-column/), those who need can use this.

Using this plugin we can specify the column(any of `date`, `date_gmt`, `modified`, `modified_gmt`) as query parameter `date_query_column` to query against value(s) given in `before` and/or `after` query parameters.

### Usage

Use the `date_query_column` parameter on any post endpoint such as `/wp/v2/posts` or `/wp/v2/pages` in combination with `before` and/or `after` parameter.

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts??after=2017-11-08T13:07:09&date_query_column=modified
```

[Github Repository](https://github.com/vignesh-s/filter_posts_using_date_query_column) of the same.